# Ansible How to copy same template for different environments with environment base list variables without group vars & template changes

Tags: ansible, jinja2, devops

We have two envs dev and prod with the same config template and different values. How can I copy the same file to both envs with different options?

**Variable file:**
vars.yml

```
dev_vars:
  hostname: monitor.dev.com
  pass: 12345
prod_vars:
  hostname: monitor.prod.com
  pass: 6789
user: monitor
```

**Hosts file**: hosts

```
[monitoring:children]
dev
prod
[dev]
dev1-ec2.dev.com
[prod]
prod1-ec2.prod.com
```

**Template file:** config.j2

```
host: {{ hostname }}
password: {{ pass }}
```

**Playbook**

```
- hosts: monitoring
  vars_files:
      - "vars.yml"
  tasks:
    #Common tasks
    - name: Create user
      user: {{ user }}
    #ENV specific tasks
    - name: copy file to dev
      template: config.j2
      when: "'dev' in group_names"
    - name: copy file to prod
      template: config.j2
      when: "'prod' in group_names"
```

I don't want to define variables inside inventory with group variables, All variables should be in the same variables file, And the template should be the same. Is there a way to process the variables differently at the tasks level? And Which way is easy dictionaries or lists?

Comment: `And Which way is easy ...  ?` => to define group vars in your inventory ;) Why are you reinventing the wheel? If you really need to have those vars in a single file, just put them directly in `hosts` with `[dev:vars]` and `[prod:vars]` stanza. Going your way is possible but will need to define group_vars anyway like the environment. You will not be able get that from the group: ansible does not know which "primary" group a machine is in.

Comment: @Zeitounator users are restricted to change only the vars file. And I am able to achieve it with the help of ```vars``` at the task level like  ```vars: env_vars: {{ dev_vars }}``` but this requires a template change as ```{{ env_vars[hostname] }} ```.So looking for the right approach.

Comment: Are you aware that there can be several `group_vars` directories, one possible place being adjacent to your playbook ?

Comment: @Zeitounator yes I am aware of it. I am not looking to add any new folders or files You can see my answer below so you may get a picture of what exactly I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this with the help of vars at the task level with a small template change as below. But looking for the way without changing the template.

**Template**

```
host: {{ env_vars.hostname }}
password: {{ env_vars.pass }}
```

**Playbook**

```
- hosts: monitoring
  vars_files:
      - "vars.yml"
  tasks:
    #Common tasks
    - name: Create user
      user: {{ user }}
    #ENV specific tasks
    - name: copy file to dev
      template: config.j2
      when: "'dev' in group_names"
      vars:
        env_vars: "{{  dev_vars }}"
    - name: copy file to prod
      template: config.j2
      when: "'prod' in group_names"
      vars:
        env_vars: "{{  prod_vars }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only one quick and dirty example but this can be achieved dynamically with a very little addition to your inventory. As stated in my above commentx, this still somewhat reinvent group vars and much better alternatives are possible IMO.

Add to your inventory (once no further edit needed)

```
[dev:vars]
env=dev
[prod:vars]
env=prod
```

Then your playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: monitoring

  vars_files:
      - "vars.yml"

  vars:
    env_vars: "{{ lookup('vars', env + '_vars') }}"
    hostname: "{{ env_vars.hostname }}"
    pass: "{{ env_vars.pass }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Create user
      user: {{ user }}

    - name: copy file to relevant environment
      template: config.j2
```

Comment: This requires a template change to read from ```env_vars``` which I was achieved without inventory file changes. Is it possible without template change?

Comment: Are you somewhat using an outdated version of ansible ? Example using 2.10: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/5c6004a107c3d4a6e349ea2824badb5b/2b1c0c76100184173bdc4a8742e9e367e640cb4a. Note that you can remove the need for `lookup` by slightly changing your env_vars definitions: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/5c6004a107c3d4a6e349ea2824badb5b/e8e5a9f3c4de62c0cba4b7374ccd8d3a2c98ecc3

Comment: Why would this require a template change ? I'm using the exact same variable name you used in you self-answer.

Comment: That's the main problem, I commented as I am able to do it with the template change in my answer. But I am looking for a with-out template change. you can see the difference of template in my question & answer.

Comment: I edited with a solution working as you expect. Meanwhile it is far from ideal and I strongly suggest you review your requirement and.... => use group_vars.

Comment: Thanks, this will be problem as I have many variables. I'll go with vars at task level option for now.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike var files, IMO `{host,group}_vars` is better.

```
mkdir -p inventory/group_vars/{all,dev,prod}
echo -ne 'user: monitor\n' > inventory/group_vars/all/main.yml
echo -ne 'hostname: monitor.dev.com\npass: 12345\n' > inventory/group_vars/dev/main.yml
echo -ne 'hostname: monitor.prod.com\npass: 6789\n' > inventory/group_vars/prod/main.yml
mv hosts inventory/
```

And drop `vars.yml` from playbook.

```
ansible -i inventory/ <playbook>
```

Or...

```
- name: copy file to dev
  template: config.j2
    src: config.j2
    dest: config
  vars:
    hostname: "{{ lookup('vars', item + '_vars').hostname }}"
    pass: "{{ lookup('vars', item + '_vars').pass }}"
  loop:
    - dev
    - prod
  when: inventory_hostname in groups[item]
```

Comment: Yes, But ansible folder/files structure is one important thing we don't want to change. it has a lot of other dependencies which I can't explain all here.